# How to create list item in an external list using SharePoint workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, rest, external-list, visual-studio-2013

Environment: **SharePoint 2013 SP1**

I have an **External List** displaying data exposed through a **WCF** service. Creating, Reading, Updating and Deleting (**CRUD**) items in the external list works fine in the browser.

I need to be able to perform CRUD operations on the external list from a SharePoint workflow attached to a normal SharePoint list, regardless if it is:

- a **SPD 2010** workflow,
- a **SPD 2013** workflow,
- a **VS** workflow,
- using **REST API** or not.

Any solution is good!

What I have tried so far is:

1. SPD 2010 workflow on normal SharePoint list with **Create List Item** action on one of the External Lists I have. The problem is that after selecting an external list, I cannot set any field of that external list because it does not display any.
2. SPD 2013 workflow on normal list with **Call HTTP web service** action using the external list's REST API. I can get the **FormDigestValue** just fine via "*[site url]/_api/contextinfo*" to set the **X-RequestDigest** header of a second **Call HTTP web service** action that is supposed to create an item in the external list:

   - **X-RequestDigest** header is set to *0x...*, namely the form digest value
   - **Accept** header is set to *application/json;odata=verbose*
   - **Content-Type** header is set to *application/json;odata=verbose*

   I am using an **App Steps** for each **Call HTTP web service** action, where the App Step runs with *FullControl* on the web where the normal list and the external lists are.

   I provide the correct metadata and list item type, plus the external list fields that need to be set for a new item.
   The **ResponseCode** of the second **Call HTTP web service** action is *Created*, so it tells me that the item is created, but in reality it is not. The **ResponseBody** contains only **null** values for the fields.

   The same happens if I use Postman or Fiddler to make a POST request to http://sharepoint/sites/dev/_api/lists/getbytitle('My_External_List')/items using the same headers from above and some input data.

   The STATUS code I get is **201 Created**. The JSON response I get from this POST request shows **"BdcIdentity": null** instead of some *0x...* value, and *d/__metadata/uri* contains **/GetItemByStringId(null)** instead of **/GetItemByStringId(** *value of BdcIdentity* **)**.

   I do not understand what goes wrong, especially because POST requests with the **"X-HTTP-Method":"DELETE"** work just fine, so it does not look like an authentication or authorization problem.

   3. I still have not tried using a Visual Studio workflow with the **HttpSend** method.

Does anyone have any idea why I have problem with creating an external list item via REST API? Or does anyone know a sure-fire solution to write to an external list from a workflow in SP 2013?

Answer (score 0):

late but maybe you should have a look on my answere here regarding to SP 2013 Workflows:
[Workflow to read data from external list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/161468/workflow-to-read-data-from-external-list/161480#161480)

As for the REST call outside of a Workflow to create a list item in a external list. I had the exact same problem. I got no error and the returned list item had only "null" values. I am pretty sure that this is a bug in the SharePoint 2013 APIs.

For an example how to access external lists with 2010 Workflows see my provided link as well. There is a example how to do it.